# Alert -- libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: swift

I am trying to display an alert message if the passwords match. Everything works very well:

1) Web service is called and returns the password

2) The flow enters the if condition that relates to a match in password

```
    if(userPasswd == sysPasswd)
    {
        displayAlert(userMessage: "Welcome! You have been authenticated")
        return
    }
```

The displayAlert function gets called successfully:

```
    func displayAlert(userMessage: String)
    {
    // create the alert
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // add an action (button)
    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

    // show the alert
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When the last statement is executed it gives this error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Why is this happening? I am a beginner in Swift and still learning the ropes. There are no yellow flags etc.

Comment: Are you sure that `self` exists when the network method returns?

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger to see the exact error message.

Comment: are you on the main thread while displaying the alert ? I doubt you are not..

Comment: it says Thread 3. How do I get back to main thread? Sorry but I am too new to this and this is my first app.

Comment: Please give the whole error message. They should be more (juste before the one you copied). The relevant informations are there (and it helps you understand why and avoid it next time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User interface elements can only be used on the main thread. If you are trying to update the UI from a background thread, you need to wrap your UI calls in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

```
func displayAlert() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(etc...)
        ...
    }
}
```